# Requesting assistance with 1 line of code regarding xajax

Tags: php, ajax, xajax

I am attempting to build a PHPMailer based email system for a basic website.

This is the line of code that is giving me trouble:

```
$xajax->printJavascript('xajax/');
```

Now, [this is the tutorial](http://www.finalwebsites.com/tutorials/php_ajax_contact_form.php) I am using.

Regarding the above line of code, the tutorial says this:

> How to use the code inside a webpage?
>   Place the form (variable), the function (and the includes) before of all html code. Next we need to include some JavaScript file in the documents HTML header (place also php tags):
>   `$xajax->printJavascript('xajax/');`

When I run all of the code (including: PHPMailer script; Ajax script), I get this error, on the aforementioned line of code.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object

So, my question is, do I need to in someway customize this code or make it run to a filepath of some ajax core file or something?

Answer (score 0):

I would be willing to be $xajax is not defined.  Try adding this after including the libraries but before including the call to that method:

```
$xajax = new xajax();
```

There may be some additional setup required by xajax.  A more complete code example could help troubleshoot.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance.  All of the code is in the tutorial, which is hyperlinked in the initial post.  It is a super basic ajax/xajax email system.